# How to pause command when it output some string?

Tags: monitoring

I need a tool that monitors output of other command, and when it prints specified string, eg. "error", stops monitored command. Then I modify some environment and files and continue job. Is it possible?

Edit:
Example:

Have a following job.sh

```
for i in $(ls)
do
    echo file $i
    sleep 0.1
    cat $i
done
```

When run in folder containing files a.txt and b.txt, I want to pause job.sh after it print `file b.txt` for editing it, then continue job.sh and see new b.txt content. 
I can't touch job.sh as it is actually compiled C program.
Sleep symbolizes that pausing do not have to be immediate, but still fast.

Comment: You can't modify the environment of the process you are monitoring. Are you instead intending to _rerun_ the command?

Comment: I do not mean shell environment variables, but files on disk. I do not want rerun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% ./mystery
a
b
c
%
```

One could issue the `STOP` signal to a program and then `CONT` to continue it; the following TCL code waits for `b` to appear in the output and at that point stops the process, which should remain stopped until the user types a line for `expect_user` to act on (at minimum a newline).

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn -noecho ./mystery
set spid [exp_pid]
expect -ex b { exec kill -STOP $spid; send_user "STOP\n" }
expect_user -re . { exec kill -CONT $spid }
expect eof
```

This of course has all sorts of problems, such as if `mystery` runs too quickly, or if the output is buffered, etc. I had to slow the C down and turn off buffering for it to work out:

```
% cat mystery.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, (char *) NULL, _IONBF, (size_t) 0);
    printf("a\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("b\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("c\n");
    return 0;
}
```

A C program may be better controlled by running it under a debugger such as `gdb`; breakpoints would be a far more accurate way to halt the execution at an exact point in the code than reacting to I/O. Debugging symbols will help but are not necessary:

```
% gdb mystery
Reading symbols from mystery...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) quit
% otool -dtv mystery | grep callq
0000000100000f26        callq   0x100000f70
0000000100000f32        callq   0x100000f6a
0000000100000f3c        callq   0x100000f76
0000000100000f48        callq   0x100000f6a
0000000100000f52        callq   0x100000f76
0000000100000f5e        callq   0x100000f6a
```

So this is actually on a Mac (disassembly will vary by platform). The above are the `setvbuf`, `printf`, and `sleep` calls so with the start address

```
% otool -dtv mystery | sed 3q
mystery:
_main:
0000000100000f06        pushq   %rbp
% perl -E 'say 0x0000000100000f52 - 0x0000000100000f06'
76
% gdb mystery
Reading symbols from mystery...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b *main + 76
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000f52
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/jhqdoe/tmp/mystery
a
b

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000100000f52 in main ()
(gdb)
```

And then you can do whatever is necessary and continue the program as desired.

Another idea would be to use `LD_PRELOAD` to adjust how the program behaves, assuming of course that the most sensible option—recompiling the program from source—is not possible. Yet another option would be to [patch the C binary to behave as desired](https://blog.0patch.com/2017/11/did-microsoft-just-manually-patch-their.html).

Comment: TCL solution works for me, thanks! As job is long-running, I added `set timeout -1` after shebang.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read` which waits for user input before proceeding

**Example:**

This program runs a loop and  prints output of `ls -lhtr` , waits for user input ( Press enter or any other character ) and then again prints output and continues the process in an infinite loop

```
#!/bin/bash

while (true); do
        ls -lhtr;
        read i;
done
```

So basically inlace of `ls -lhtr` , you can use the command whose output you need to monitor , once you are finished with modifying  environment  and files, you can press any key to continue monitoring the command output again

Comment: Here stopped command is a continously printing script. It was modified to be stopped. I want to stop command without modifying it.

Comment: @Chocimier you can call the continuously printing script from another script , so there will be no need of modifying the command. you are basically creating a wrapper over your existing script , e.g. replace `ls -lhtr` with `bash test.sh`

Comment: I need to break single command, not loop. See added example in question.